# Pass cast ref-to-pointer from base to derived type

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, reference

I have a situation where I'm getting a reference to a pointer as a return type from a function. The reference is important, because I need the calling code to be able to modify the pointer.

But I also want to be able to return that through another function, this time cast to a ref-to-pointer of a derived type. This is causing a compiler error that I can't quite figure out how to get around.

This program shows what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        virtual ~Foo() {}
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
        virtual ~Bar() {}
        void doit() { std::cout << "Done" << std::endl; }
};

class Container
{
    public:
        void setFoo(Foo *f) { _foo = f; }
        Foo*& getFoo() { return _foo; }

        Foo *_foo;
};

class OtherContainer : public Container
{
    public:
        void setBar(Bar *b) { setFoo(dynamic_cast<Foo*>(b)); }

        Bar*& getBar() 
        {
            return static_cast<Bar*&>(getFoo());
        }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    OtherContainer container;
    Bar bar;
    Bar otherBar;

    container.setBar(&bar);
    
    container.getBar() = &otherBar;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is returning this error:

```
g++     refptr.cc   -o refptr
refptr.cc: In member function ‘Bar*& OtherContainer::getBar()’:
refptr.cc:41:20: error: invalid ‘static_cast’ from type ‘Foo*’ to type ‘Bar*&’
   41 |             return static_cast<Bar*&>(getFoo());
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: refptr] Error 1
```

I've tried changing the static cast to just <Bar*> instead of <Bar*&> but then it says it "cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Bar*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Bar*’," which makes sense to me (and I didn't really expect that to work).

Is there even a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: _"Is there even a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?"_ no, you're not allowed to use a `Foo*` as a `Bar*`. But your code is designed wrong if you want to do this.

Comment: To give more context specific to your critique (which is valid as far as it goes)...I have a container holding a base class, which provides various methods (beyond just containment, say). I then have a template derived from the container, where the template parameter is a class derived from the base class. The derived container fully checks incoming pointers to make sure they are absolutely Bar's, even though the underlying (base) class will store them as Foo*'s. So, on retrieval I absolutely know they are actually Bar*'s.

Comment: *Is there even a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?*  Probably.  The approach you've taken here, as you discovered, doesn't work.  What are you trying to do?  What's wrong with `container.setBar(&otherBar);`?

Comment: @DanielEngel No, you are conflating objects and their pointers. You have `Bar` objects, not `Bar*` pointers. Even though you can point a `Foo*` at a `Bar`, a `Foo*` is still not a `Bar*`.

Comment: @Eljay, to give even more context: The getter in question is really an operator[] so that you can do something like container["Key"] = &otherBar (similar to std::map). The outer container's operator[] doesn't override, but completely overshadow's the inner container's operator[] so that it can return the different type. But I want the same dynamic to work. Since the outer container isn't privy to the inner container's inner workings, it relies on the inner container's operator[] to obtain the reference to the stored pointer.

Comment: ` I need the calling code to be able to modify the pointer`, sounds like you didn't really consider modeling ownership in your design and you have shared ownership of your classes and your Container should hold a std::shared_ptr<Foo>.  Also with all this casting why not give Foo a virtual method `doIt` (that does nothing) it could really cleanup your design, because all this casting is a design smell too (at least it is for me).

Answer (score -2):

After some fooling around, I found that a way to get this to work is to turn the return value from the inner getter into a pointer. Then reinterpret_cast that and dereference for the return to the outer getter:

```
class OtherContainer : public Container
...
    Bar*& getBar() 
    {   
        Foo **ptr = &getFoo();
        return *reinterpret_cast<Bar**>(ptr);
    }
...
```

As explained in my answer to Passer By's comment, I can do this /only/ because (within the full context of what I'm making) I absolutely know that the stored pointer to the base class (Foo) is really a pointer to the derived class (Bar).

**Edit**

With help from commenters, I landed on a different solution. I want as much of type-checking on the way in as reasonable, with natural type presentation on the way out. I've modified my example code to be a little closer (contextually) to what I'm going for (e.g., a templated derived class). I am grateful for the critiques offered so far; thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Foo
{
    public:
        virtual ~Foo() {}
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
        virtual ~Bar() {}
        void doit() { std::cout << "Done" << std::endl; }
};

class Container
{
    public:
        void set(Foo *f) { setPtr(f); }
        Foo*& get()
        {
            void **ptr = &getPtr();
            return *reinterpret_cast<Foo**>(_foo);
        }

        void checkAs(void *p)
        {
            std::cout << ((_foo == p) ? "it works" : "it fails") << std::endl;
        }


    protected:
        void setPtr(void *p) { _foo = p; }
        void*& getPtr() { return _foo; }

    private:
        void *_foo;
};

// C is expected to be derived from Foo
template <class C>
class OtherContainer : public Container
{
    public:
        // hide, not override (would need to continue pattern through subclasses...anoying)
        void set(Foo *f)
        {
            C *c = dynamic_cast<C *>(f);
            if (c == nullptr)
            {
                // don't store - not a C *
                return;
            }

            setPtr(c); 
        }

        void set(C *c) { setPtr(c); }

        // hide, not override
        C*& get() 
        {
            void **ptr = &getPtr();
            return *reinterpret_cast<C**>(ptr);
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    OtherContainer<Bar> container;
    Bar bar;
    Bar otherBar;

    container.set(&bar);
    container.get() = &otherBar;
    container.checkAs(&otherBar);

    return 0;
}
```

The template class OtherContainer is intended to be the outermost exposed class of the framework that this would be a part of. I think this approach should always work intuitively, regardless of compiler implementation...(or will it?)

**Edit #2**

I want to thank everybody who took the time to comment on my question and proposed self-answer. I am a stubborn badger when it comes to giving up on an idea, but y'all have convinced me that this particular idea won't work the way I currently have it conceived. I need to find a different way to accomplish what I'm after. Thank you all.

Comment: Easy to break if there is multiple inheritance involved.  Might as well use a `void*` as the backing store **to avoid the undefined behavior**, and have the **caller** deal with the ramifications of casting to/from.

Comment: Just don't. Any design involving dynamic polymorhpic classes should (normally) not involve any (static/reinterpret) casting at all.  (maybe ok if you dynamic cast between interfaces to detect capabilities at runtime, or when type-erasure in a template can guarantee something was of the type you cast to).

Comment: This is wrong and has undefined behavior _even if_ you know that the pointer points to a subobject of a `Bar`. You are confusing the pointed-to class object with the pointer itself. They are two completely distinct objects and this is an aliasing violation on the pointer itself, not the class object. Even if aliasing is not a problem, it will result in a wrong pointer depending on the class layout, because it doesn't properly account for base class offsets as `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` do (which is why `reinterpret_cast` is always wrong to deal with class hierarchies).

Comment: @user17732522, I am always eager to learn the C++ specifics more deeply. Are you saying that static_cast<Derived *>(static_cast<Base *>(derived)) is not always == reinterpret_cast<Derived *>(static_cast<Base *>(derived))? Hmm... still, it's reasonable to expect that there's a way within the language to accomplish the interface I'm after, without shifting the burden entirely to the to make sure types are appropriately used.

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer, "...if you dynamic cast between interfaces..." - that's exactly what I'm doing. dynamic_cast with test-for-failure on bringing pointer in. But the point that user17732522 makes has me second-guessing even that, now. Still, there has to be a way...

Comment: @DanielEngel According to C++ specification `static_cast<Derived *>(static_cast<Base *>(derived)) ` is only equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<Derived *>(static_cast<Base *>(derived))` if `Dervived` is a standard-layout class and `Base` is its first base class in declaration order, i.e. if `Derived` and `Base` are _pointer-interconvertible_, as can be tested with [`std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of).

Comment: @DanielEngel But that doesn't apply here anyway, because you are not casting to `Derived*`. You are casting to `Derived**`. There is an extra pointer in there which makes it _always_ wrong according to specification and also in practice, because it is an aliasing violation between `Base*` and `Derived*` that compilers actually do perform optimizations on (while the pointer-interconvertibility issue is often not as problematic in practice if the base happens to still have offset zero in the derived class).

Comment: @user17732522, "...you are not casting...": Understood. But the only reason reinterpret casting to Derived** would not work is if the memory location of the start of the base object is not the same as the memory location of the stat of the derived object - which you've convinced me is a real issue. See my edited answer...thoughts? (Thanks for the insight!)

Comment: Correction: In my second to last comment, I shouldn't have written "_first base class_". It applies to all base classes.

Comment: @DanielEngel Even if that is the case there is still an aliasing violation as I said. In C++ (and C) it is not allowed to access an object of one type (e.g. `Base*`) as a lvalue of another type (e.g. `Derived*`). This is meant to allow the compiler better optimization possibilities during pointer aliasing analysis and compilers make use of it. See "Type aliasing" at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast. Compilers may have options to disable such optimizations, e.g. `-fno-strict-aliasing` in GCC/Clang. But formally it is always UB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257121/discussion-between-daniel-engel-and-user17732522).